# Graphs being plotted despite being undefined.

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

I've not really understood why this happens. I'm quite new to the idea of limits, etc. But I've seen that when you use a grapher, it plots undefined points. For example in the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2+x-6}{x-2}$, the value $f(2)$ would be undefined, so why does a grapher not show that $f$ is undefined at $2$ and instead carries on through it? It seems to be plotting the $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2+x-6}{x-2}$.

I hope this makes sense, apologies if it doesn't.

[image: Graph of $\frac{x^2+x-6}{x-2}$]

Comment: Smart plotting software can show it, sometimes.  Try this in Mathematica. `Plot[(x^2 + x - 6)/(x - 2), {x, 0, 4}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]]}]`.  The point is auto-detected, we just have to turn on marking it by setting the style to red.  Plotting software that can do this must be *very* smart because this sort of thing can only be detected using symbolic computation.  Most such software only evaluates the function numerically at certain points and then connects the dots with lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way a computer can make a graph of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is to divide $[a,b]$ up in $n$ ascending points $x_1,\dots x_n$ with $x_1=a$ and $x_n=b$ and then draw straight lines between $\left(x_i,f(x_i)\right)$ and $\left(x_{i+1},f(x_{i+1})\right)$. The number $n$ and the ways the partition $x_1,\dots x_n$ is chosen depends on the software and is often adjustable. If I use the following *Mathematica* code

```
Plot[(x^2 + x - 6)/(x - 2), {x, 0, 4}]
```

to plot your function I get the following image.

[image]

If I now ask *Mathematica* which points it used to plot I get a long list of which these are a few:

$$\dots,(1.88078, 4.88078), (1.96018, 4.96018), (2.03801,5.03801), (2.12244, 5.12244),\dots.$$

So we see that the point $x=2$ wasn't sampled and as a result we might as well have asked it to plot $f(x)=x+3$. The shortcomings of this naive way of plotting are felt stronger when we for instance plot $f(x)=\tan(x)$. The code

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

produces the following image.

[image]

The software does not know that the function is not defined at $x=\frac{1}{2}\pi$. Sophisticated software often knows how or has a way to deal with this. In *Mathematica* this

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 0}]
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The limit is identical from the left and from the right, so there is only an infinitely small point at $x=2$ where there is nothing to plot.

But since you don't have infinite precision in your plot, it "looks" as though the plot just goes "right through" as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Unsophisticated graphing software evaluates the function at a number of points, and then draws straight lines between the points it obtained. There is typically not one function evaluation per pixel, and even if there is, the odds of hitting the exact point where your function is undefined are quite low.

Answer (score -1):

That graph is wrong. There should be a hole at $x=2$, as you correctly guessed. The correct plot are two lines with arrows at the ends where they touch the point $(2,5)$.

Comment: Well, it depends on how the graphing is done. The "hole" is infinitely small and so it cannot be seen unless it is explictly illustrated.

Comment: @Eff Yes, the hole is infinitely small, but graphing rules dictate that such infinitely small holes are then shown using other means (i.e., arrows at the ends of lines). We must know that a picture of a graph is only an idealized portrayal of what it actually is, and it must abide by some rules we made--including the one about making holes visible.